# SwiftUI Show/Dismiss Keyboard

Tags: swiftui, keyboard

This code below show and hide TextField keyboard perfectly except this warning message keep showing to me when run the code, did anyone can help to avoid this warning please ???

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

struct FirstResponderTextFiels: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var text: String
    let placeholder: String
    @Binding var showKeyboard: Bool
    
    
    // Create the coordinator
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        
        @Binding var text: String
        @Binding var showKeyboard: Bool
        var becameFirstResponder = false
        
        init(text: Binding<String>, showKeyboard: Binding<Bool>) {
            self._text = text
            self._showKeyboard = showKeyboard
        }
        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            text = textField.text ?? ""
        }
        
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text, showKeyboard: $showKeyboard)
    }
    
    
    // Create the textfield
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.placeholder = placeholder
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        
        if context.coordinator.showKeyboard {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
            context.coordinator.showKeyboard = false
        }
    }
    
}
```

The warning message

[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the component, but it doesn't appear to be working for me, so I'm skeptical about leaving this as an "answer", but you can try wrapping that line in `DispatchQueue.main.async { }`

Comment: I did this and that keep hiding the keyboard and not allow it to show !!

Answer (score 0):

After review the code I found if I remove this part of code it has no effect and it just work fine

```
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    
    if context.coordinator.showKeyboard {
        uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
       context.coordinator.showKeyboard = false   // <--- Remove it
    }
}
```